# Get most recent distinct records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

Every resort has many snow reports. 
I want to get the most recent snow report for every resort where the field snow_summit in the table snow_reports should be > 0 .

So I tried to select distinct on resort_id which is the fkey in snow_reports and order by updated_at but  this it not possible since updated_at does not occur in the select.

So how do I get only the most recent records of an associated mode in rails4 (on postgres)?

```
SnowReport belongs_to Resort
Resort has_many snow_reports
Table snow_reports has id,resort_id,updated_at,snow_summit
```

Ideally the result is joined for performance reasons.

My approach fails

```
SnowReport.includes(:resort).select(:resort_id).group(:resort_id).having('max(snow_summit)> 0').order('max(snow_reports.updated_at) DESC')
```

since SnowReport.id is nil

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<SnowReport id: nil, resort_id: 1735>, ...
```

edit:

I found a solution in plain sql.
How can I transform this to rails ?

```
   select * from resorts where id in (select distinct(resort_id) from snow_reports where snow_summit > 0 and created_at > (now()- interval '3 days')
and created_at in (select max(created_at) from snow_reports group by resort_id));
```

Comment: do you have records with such specifications in your table

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SnowReport.includes(:resort).select(:id, :resort_id).where("snow_summit > ?", 0).order("updated_at DESC").group(:resort_id)
```

It may work.

Comment: like this the snowreport_id is nil

Comment: @dc10 Can you send me the output here

Comment: SnowReport.includes(:resort).select(:resort_id).where("snow_summit > ?", 0).order("updated_at DESC")
  SnowReport Load (3.5ms)  SELECT "snow_reports"."resort_id" FROM "snow_reports"  WHERE (snow_summit > 0)  ORDER BY updated_at DESC
  Resort Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "resorts".* FROM "resorts"  WHERE "resorts"."id" IN (1727,......)
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<SnowReport id: nil, resort_id: 1727>, #<SnowReport id: nil, resort_id: 1647>, #<SnowReport id: nil, resort_id: 1581>, ...]> 
2.1.1 :150 >

Comment: @Gwori Hold on, I just double checked and i noticed that there is no distinct or group condition so `SnowReport.includes(:resort).select(:id, :resort_id).where("snow_summit > ?", 0).order("updated_at DESC")`   results in `SELECT "snow_reports"."id", "snow_reports"."resort_id" FROM "snow_reports"  WHERE (snow_summit > 0)  ORDER BY updated_at DESC` which return all ids

Comment: @dc10 I overlooked it so forgot to add group condition please check my answer I edited it.

Comment: thanks again. we re close but not done yet :( ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "snow_reports.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65344/discussion-between-gowri-and-dc10).